# Image in object element javascript

Tags: javascript

I have to random quote and for better design i want to put image of man who said that.
For example:
my "try"

```
 var quote = [
      '\"Don\'t cry because it\'s over, smile because it happened.\" ―  Dr. Seuss', '\"Be yourself; everyone else is already taken.\" ― Oscar Wilde',
  '\"A room without books is like a body without a soul.\" ― Marcus Tullius Cicero',
  '\"You only live once, but if you do it right, once is enough.\" ― Mae West',
  '\"Be the change that you wish to see in the world.\" ― Mahatma Gandhi']
```

I need the picture of Seuss in it so how can i do it?I have some ideas but i don't know how to realize them.I need help!My site does everything it has to.

Comment: where do you want the image exactly ??? all I see is an array

Comment: You need array of object that have 2 properties, `quote` and `photo_url`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you've not included how you're currently displaying the quotes in that array I'm just going to assume that you're asking ...

> How do I store an image for each quote inside the array?

That can be done by making each item inside the array an object, like this:

```
var quotes = [
  {
    text: '\"Don\'t cry because it\'s over, smile because it happened.\" ―  Dr. Seuss',
    picture: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/19/Ted_Geisel_NYWTS_2_sepia.jpg'
  }
]
```

I would also recommend putting the name of the author into another property like this:

```
var quotes = [
  {
    author: 'Dr. Seuss',
    text: "Don't cry because it's over, smile because it happened.",
    picture: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/19/Ted_Geisel_NYWTS_2_sepia.jpg'
  }
]
```

To display the quotes you can loop other them and get `author`, `text` and `picture` by using `quote.author`, ...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can achieve what you want with a multi-dimentional array.

```
var quote = [
  ['\"Don\'t cry because it\'s over, smile because it happened.\" ―  Dr. Seuss', 'http://example.com/randomimage.jpg'], 
  ['\"Be yourself; everyone else is already taken.\" ― Oscar Wilde', 'http://example.com/randomimage.jpg'],
  ['\"A room without books is like a body without a soul.\" ― Marcus Tullius Cicero', 'http://example.com/randomimage.jpg'],
  ['\"You only live once, but if you do it right, once is enough.\" ― Mae West', 'http://example.com/randomimage.jpg'],
  ['\"Be the change that you wish to see in the world.\" ― Mahatma Gandhi', 'http://example.com/randomimage.jpg']
];
```

Answer (score 0):

**Assuming** you want the image beside the quote (not inline). You could just have the `img src` in that quote variable such as:

```
var quote = {
    'author_img' : '/imgs/author/Seuss',
    'quote' : '...'
};
```

You'd access it like this:

```
quote.author_img 
quote.quote
```

Super basic code-snippet:

```js
var quote = {
    'author_img' : 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d1/Portrait_Gandhi.jpg',
    'quote' : 'Happiness is when what you think, what you say, and what you do are in harmony.'
};

$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('button').click(function(){
        $('#quote img').attr('src', quote.author_img);
        $('#quote p').text(quote.quote);
    });
});
```

```css
#quote img{
  width: 100px;
  float:left;
  margin-right: 25px;
}

.clearfix:after{
  float:none;
  display:table;
  content:"";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="quote" class="clearfix">
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdvUu.png?s=128&g=1" alt="" title=""/>
<p>Default message</p>
</div>

<button>CLICK ME TO CHANGE QUOTE</button>
```